# Can we put less oil in Shamash of the Hanukiya

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia

Those who light with oil, can they put an amount of oil in the Shamash so that it will light less than 30 minutes? (The other candles will of course be light for at least 30 minutes)

Comment: If you need a shamash for the first 20 minutes, why wouldn't you need it for the last 10?

Comment: Recall there is no hiddur of using oil for the shamash. Wax or electric is equally effective

Comment: I thought one of the benefits of the shamash was that, if you use the light of the Hanukia, you could claim it came from the shamash. According this it would need to burn 30 minutes as well

Comment: The difference between 20 and 30 minutes worth of oil is just a few drops. I don't see the point.